# Reading and Writing Temp Files in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, temp

I'm using a temporary text file to submit html web form data to a database. Basically the process is:
Submit form data ==> Write form data to temp.txt ==> submit temp.txt data to database.
I know how to write data to text file and how to read data from text file. 
How do I make sure data is written to database immediately after the text file is closed?

Comment: 1. Show some code. 2. Why not do it in memory?

Comment: it is better you save data in file it self ..y overhead of writing again.:)

Comment: Why just why!?. You can input the form data directory into the database. Why make a temp file??? What is it you try to gain??? You can access all the data with `$_REQUEST` and if there are files uploaded use `$_FILES`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the point in writing the form data to a text file when it can be written to the database immediately. Writing it to a text file first just slows the process down.

In any case:

```
$data = $_POST['data']; 
// Make sure to check the data before insertion to the database!
$file = fopen('temp.txt', 'w');
fwrite($file, $data);
fclose($file);

// Write the data to the database here.
```

or

```
$data = $_POST['data']; 
// Make sure to check the data before insertion to the database!
$file = fopen('temp.txt', 'w+');
fwrite($file, $data);
// Write the data here, and save yourself from having to open the file again.
fclose($file);
```

Comment: You should really use [`tmpfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tmpfile.php).

Comment: thanks Xenolithic. I'm a bit of a noob at this and was going through a tutorial that suggested the method I've posted. This clears it up quite!!

Comment: I've never used that function before, but I'll keep it in mind, thanks. The main reason I decided to go with `fopen()` is because the asked specified the file name/extension, so I just assumed it was an actual file, not just a legitimate temporary file. :P

Comment: Yes, tmpfile seems to do the job.